# A proper way to use mutex in c++ ncurses project?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I can't find a way to write a good condition(s) to solve my problem. As you can see on an included image there is a line in a middle of a screen and balls are endlessly going up and down and disappearing after some time. New balls are also appearing endlessly.

[image: my image]

My task is to use mutex so that only N balls (2 or 3) can be above the line and the rest are waiting for their turn.

I have tried a few options, here is the most recent one. It probably doesn't make much sense but I have no other ideas for the moment:

Fragment from ball.cpp:

```
Ball::Ball(int nr)
{
    this->nr = nr;
    changeDirection();
    this->x = 40;
    this->y = 24;
    this->lastX = 0;
    this->lastY = 0;
    this->bounceCounter = 0;
    this->isAboveTheLine = false;
}
```

........

```
if(y < 12) {
    isAboveTheLine = true;
}
else if(y >= 12) {
    isAboveTheLine = false;
}
```

And from main.cpp:

```
std::mutex m;

void ballFunction(int a)
{   
    int counter = 2;
    int nr = a;
    while (run && shared->balls[nr]->bounceCounter < 5)
    {
        usleep(50000);

        shared->balls[nr]->updateBall();

        if(shared->balls[nr]->isAboveTheLine == true) {         
            counter++;
        }
        else if(shared->balls[nr]->isAboveTheLine == false) {
            counter--;
        }

        if(counter >= 3) {
            m.lock();
        }
        else if (counter<2) {
            m.unlock();
        }
    }

    shared->balls[nr]->x = -1;
    shared->balls[nr]->y = -1;
}
```

---

Edit: I have added int main():

```
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    window = new Window();

    int i = 0;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    std::thread threadWindow(updateWindow2);
    std::thread threadExit(exit);

    while(run) {
        window->addBall();
        threads.push_back(std::thread(ballFunction, i));
        i++;
        sleep(1);
    }

    threadWindow.join();
    threadExit.join();

    for(int j=2; j<i+2; j++) {
        threads[j].join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't work at all. Am I going in a right direction or do I need a different approach?

Comment: @MarekR I have added more code for more context.

Comment: Off topic: `if (y < 12) { isAboveTheLine = true; } else if(y >= 12) { isAboveTheLine = false; }` can be written as `isAboveTheLine = y < 12;`, etc.

Comment: Off topic: also do not additionaly check in `else if` exactly the opposite you checked in `if`. `else {...}` will be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If answer your question directly, I would use [`condition_variable`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/) for that. Wait until free place for a ball appears (count of balls in the upper part becomes less than ball count limit). Notify other threads when a ball leaves the limited-ball-number area:

```
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
int counter = 2;

void ballFunction(int a)
{   
    int nr = a;
    while (shared->balls[nr]->bounceCounter < 5)
    {
        usleep(50000);

        bool previousIsAbove = shared->balls[nr]->isAboveTheLine;
        shared->balls[nr]->updateBall();
        // check if state changed
        if (previousIsAbove == shared->balls[nr]->isAboveTheLine) continue;

        if(previousIsAbove) // ball went down the line
        {           
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(m);
            counter++;
            cv.notify_one();
        }
        else
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(m);
            cv.wait(locker, [&](){return !run || counter > 0;});
            if (!run) return;
            counter--;
        }
    }

    shared->balls[nr]->x = -1;
    shared->balls[nr]->y = -1;
}
```

But the code has much more issues and I will explain the most crucial.

First of all your `counter` is a non-static local variable inside the `ballFunction()`. All `ballFunction` callers will have their own version of `counter`, but you want ot use it as one single shared variable for all threads. Put it outside the `ballFunction()`. Also you initialize it with `2` so I assume you want to use it as a number of free places above the line. But you increment it when the ball goes above the line and check it against '2' and '3'. Do the opposite - decrement free places count when the ball goes up over the line and check to be more than `0` before decrementing and letting the ball go up further.

Assuming you fixed that, you still read/write the `counter` value without any critical section handling and thread synchronisation. That could lead to data races and is *undefined behaviour (not a program)*. Work with shared data in thread-safe way only. For example if you use `mutex` to synchronize threads (like in this case), access it only "under locked mutex" to limit number of threads simultaneously working with shared data to one. If you decide to use `atomic` instead - do the *check + increment/decrement* only with [CAS (compare & swap) atomic operation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_compare_exchange).

The same is for `run` (you access it from different threads too, at least make it `volatile`). Note: do not forget to notify threads when you set your `run` to `false` (I assume you do that in `exit()`) if you use my code.

You increment the count of balls up the line every iteration for every ball that entered the upper part. Do that only at the moment of crossing the line (I do that by checking where the ball was before updating its position and where it is after that, you can also save it from previous iteration to avoid double-check).

I didn't touch issues of readability, style etc., only main multithreading and logic issues.

PS:

> New balls are also appearing endlessly

because you spawn them endlessly here:

```
while(run) {
    window->addBall();
    threads.push_back(std::thread(ballFunction, i));
    i++;
    sleep(1);
}
```

I don't know what you want your program to do instead.